# Using plain-draggable library with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use the [plain-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plain-draggable) library with my React app. To `package.json` I added: `"plain-draggable": "^2.5.14",`

Then I ran `npm i`. Upon starting the app using `react-scripts start` I see the error in the console:

```
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'anim-event' in '/Users/use/app/tom/new_version/app/node_modules/plain-draggable'`
```

I then go into the module with `cd node_modules/plain-draggable` and run `npm i`. Now it works, but I need to do this every time I run the app. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the missing dependencies in your main project rather than going to the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling it each time.

Try it in the root directory of your application;

```
npm install --save anim-event cssprefix m-class-list pointer-event
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this problem because there are quite a few dependencies in the plain-draggable, which should have been part of dependencies but are declared inside devDependencies. Check below snapshot from Github

[image]

As stated by @ozan-yurtsever, you need to install those dependencies along with plain-draggable and add it to your own dependencies section.